# VS ignores symbol _Debug in Resources.rc (Visual Studio bug ?)

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, managed

Can anybody explain me that very strange fenomenon ?

In my VS2005 Managed C++ project file (VCPROJ) is defined:

```
<Configuration
    Name="Debug|Win32"
    ....
    PreprocessorDefinitions="WIN32;_DEBUG"
    ....
</Configuration>
<Configuration
    Name="Release|Win32"
    ....
    PreprocessorDefinitions="WIN32;NDEBUG"
    ....
</Configuration>
```

Whereever I used the symbol _Debug it works perfect.
For example:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    #include "noexist.h"
#endif
```

produces an error

```
C1083: Cannot open include file: 'noexist.h': No such file or directory
```

when compiled as Debug while it compiles without error as Release.

OK.

Now comes that strange thing:
The symbol _DEBUG is completely ignored in the file Resources.rc.
Although Visual Studio itself inserts these lines:

```
VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION 1,0,0,1
 PRODUCTVERSION 1,0,0,1
 FILEFLAGSMASK 0x17L
#ifdef _DEBUG
 FILEFLAGS 0x1L
#else
 FILEFLAGS 0x0L
#endif
 FILEOS 0x4L
 FILETYPE 0x2L
 FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
etc...
```

the flag _DEBUG (and also NDEBUG) do not exist in Resources.rc.

If I insert the same lines

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    #include "noexist.h"
#endif
```

into Resources.rc it does neither produce an error compiled as Debug nor as Release!

The same applies to

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
    #include "noexist.h"
#endif
```

which compiles without error as Release and as Debug!

How is that possible ?
How can a global compiler symbol be present in one file but not in another file ?

Is this a Visual Studio bug ?

(In pure C++ projects this works fine, this problem is only in my Managed C++ project)

Is there a workaround ?

Comment: Almost certainly a VS2005 problem - it works fine in VS2012 for a `\clr` MFC application, for example.

Comment: This is just broken in the project template, it still is in VS2012.  Different build tool (rc.exe), different settings.  Right-click your project, Properties, Resources, General.  Add _DEBUG to the Preprocessor Definitions.

Comment: You are right! There are TWO settings for the Precompiler flags. One in C++/Preprocessor and another one in Resource/General. These may be different. Now it works! Thanks A LOT!

Comment: @HansPassant, you are life saver! I hate microsoft, why are there different preprocessor setings for code and resources?!

Comment: History, mostly.  The C++ build model dates from the stone age.  Too many build tools, entirely too many build options, too many shortcuts over the past 30 years that now bite anybody in the rear end.  CMake tends to be popular to tame this a bit.  But it just adds an extra layer of things that can go wrong.  Not just Microsoft's problem, if I get to choose between building Boost and visiting the dentist to get a root canal done, the dentist always wins.