# Using Preprocessor Macros in .rc Files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, embedded-resource

I have a C++ program in Visual Studio Community 2015 where I need to include a different resource for debug and release versions. Debug and release versions are differentiated by defining the `_DEBUG` macro for the debug version, otherwise leaving it undefined.
So naturally I tried to put a `#if defined(_DEBUG)` into my .rc file, but when compiling the resource compiler acts like the macro isn't defined and compiles it as it was a release version (when it is not).

How do I make the resource compiler see the macro?

Comment: The compiler does not take the 'rc' file as input, so writing C code in it is pointless (and probably harmful as well, because some other module within VS takes it as input, and that module expect a certain language (other than C)).

Comment: @barakmanos It is able to understand preprocessor statements.

Comment: You need to define `_DEBUG` on the `rc` command as well as the `cl` command.  See the file properties for the .rc file in VS.  See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381055(v=vs.85).aspx  Also `defined` may not be supported only `#ifdef` is documented - need to test.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you configured your project to define __DEBUG_ macro for this .rc file? If 'yes', then probably try replace `#if defined(_DEBUG)` with `#ifdef _DEBUG`. The second should work according to the spec - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381033(v=vs.85).aspx . Preprocessor directives supported by .rc files are not the same that supported for C/C++ sources.

Comment: Is there a way to set the same preprocessor definitions for resource compiler and compiler without having to copy paste it every time a change is made to them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS ignores symbol _Debug in Resources.rc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850863/vs-ignores-symbol-debug-in-resources-rc-visual-studio-bug)

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass a pre-processor definition to the resource compiler you must also define it in the project settings (Config Properties -> Resources -> General).